Find height of a portion of a trapezoid
In the included drawing, I am trying to find $\Delta g$.  I know a, c and $\Delta b$. The area of the large trapezoid is
$$A_L = \frac{(a+c)}{2}\Delta b$$
The area of the small trapezoid is,
$$A_S = \frac{(a+f)}{2}\Delta g$$
From other means, I know that the ratio of the areas is equal to a constant, $G$. Knowing the ratio of the areas yields,
$$\frac{A_S}{A_L} = G = \frac{(a+f)\Delta g}{(a+c)\Delta b}$$
Still, I've been having trouble calculating $\Delta g$, because I don't know f. It seems like there is enough information, but I can't seem to progress any further. Any help is appreciated.


The bases and heights are also related by similar triangles:$$\frac{c-a}{f-a} = \frac{\Delta b}{\Delta g}$$

Thanks, that was the missing piece of information that I needed.
